# What was the economic incentive for "redlining"?

Tags: economy, history, racism

Not sure if this belongs here, on Economics or on History. But anyway.

"Redlining" was the practice in the USA during the Jim Crow era of mortgage companies not offering mortgages to black people. But if black people wanted to take out mortgages, it would seem that there would be money to be made by providing them. So why did redlining persist?

- Was there an actual economic issue with black people and mortgages, e.g. the racism of wider society meant a higher probability of default?
- Were the white company owners deliberately forgoing profit out of a sense of racial solidarity?
- Were they afraid of reprisals (e.g. violence or boycotts) by the wider white population?
- Or something else?

(I'm aware of the "contract for deed" system whereby black people could get loans for houses on very disadvantageous terms, including losing everything if you missed a single payment).

Comment: Not my DV, but it might be better on H.SE, unless you claims in persited to recent times. Anyhow, I'm not sure there's an "economic incentive" for racism. Economics assumes rational actors, but I'm not entirely convinced that cognitive model is suitable for racism... The latter Q would be suitable on econ.SE, in a more abstract setting.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.sas.rochester.edu/psc/clarke/214/Arrow98.pdf) of Arrow might be interesting; has a huge number of citations. "Presumably the population of employers is not uniform in
its discriminatory tastes. Then, under the usual assumption of constant (or increasing) returns to scale, competition would imply the elimination of all but the least
discriminatory employers. If there are any non-discriminatory employers, they
would drive out the others."

Comment: On the flip side, he seems to have more Qs than answers: "Finally, what can market-based theories make of discrimination against black consumers? Sellers of houses and mortgages have refused to sell to black customers and
still refuse to some extent. It is hard to think of any market–based explanation for
refusal to sell. Sellers of automobiles sell to black customers only at higher prices. Why
does not competition prevent this discrimination, according to well-known arguments?" Yeah, econ.SE is probably the best venue.

Comment: If you post on econ.SE, it's probably best to tag with 'behavioral economics' as that's the more recent branch that deal with not entirely rational actors (although with limited success). A quick search finds some attempts of BE to treat racism https://issuu.com/peokeefe/docs/dismalscientist2020ii/s/10781198

Comment: Even though the after-effects of redlining are still affecting people of color today, this is still not a question about contemporary politics. I will migrate it to history stack exchange.